# Can a Ger Toshav own land in Eretz Yisrael?

Tags: gentiles, eretz-yisrael, real-estate, yovel, ger-toshav

Once the [*ger toshav*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ger_toshav) becomes accepted when the Yovel/Jubilee year is in effect, can the *ger toshav* own land in Eretz Yisrael?

Comment: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1410.htm The Rambam I think implies in this link that they may purchase land, in law 9. I would imagine that the purchase would be subject to the same laws that apply to all documents of land sale in Israel. That is, with very few exceptions, the sale is more of a lease, not to exceed the time between the sale and the coming Jubilee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[R Shlomo Riskin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Riskin) (the Chief Rabbi of Efrat in Israel) [writes](https://library.yctorah.org/files/2016/07/Riskin-Selling-land-in-Israel.pdf) indeed that a *ger toshav* can own land in Eretz Israel

> According to Rambam [[Avodat Kochavim 10:6]](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/912369/jewish/Avodat-Kochavim-Chapter-Ten.htm), the very term ger toshav, stranger-resident,
>   defines the fact that **any gentile who accepts the seven Noahide laws
>   of morality may be a resident in the land of Israel, may purchase or
>   rent land** or a dwelling place and may live in the midst of a Jewish
>   community in Israel!

He continues

> A ringing affirmation for Maimonides‘ position that defines **ger toshav
>   as a gentile who is permitted to dwell in the midst of the Israelites
>   in the land of Israel, and that they can therefore purchase land
>   and/or homes in Israel**, is found in one of the smaller talmudic
>   tractates, Gerim [3:3-4]:
>   
> And we may not
>   cause [the ger toshav] to dwell on or close to
>   the border [because of the danger of an
>   enemy attack], or in an unseemly dwelling
>   place, but rather in a goodly dwelling, in
>   the midst of the Land of Israel, in a place
>   where his business or artisanship can
>   prosper, as it is written: "With you shall he
>   dwell, in your midst, in whatever place he
>   will choose, in any one of your cities,
>   wherever it is beneficial to him; you must
>   not taunt him."

Answer (score 2):

Although there are opinions that do say it is okay, it is not so simple. See for example the Minchas Chinuch (284) which says the fact the Rambam does not make any distinguish the prohibition of לא תחנם applies to a goy and a ger toshav equally. Thus, it is forbidden to sell them any land, house, or anything else connected to the ground. Letting them live amongst us (hence the name גר **תושב**) is not the same as selling them land.

See שו"ת יביע אומר (יו"ד סי' מא) at length.